# How to create four lists with of size 100 million in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
j=[]
m=[]
n=[]
o=[]
for i in range(100480508):
    j.append(str(i))
    m.append(str(i))
    n.append(str(i))
    o.append(str(i))
```

Basically I am working on movie recommender systems. I want to store the details of customers in a list with the size of 100 million!!
When I execute this program , it got Killed!!

Is there any solution to solve this issue in python? How can I handle with the larger datasets in python?

Comment: Use a database instead. Your program would never need to hold 400 million strings in memory at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Martijin !! But instead of using database is it possible to do so? Basically I reading the details from the file and storing it in the list for computation...

Comment: It is a competition, that one you'll have to work out yourself. I strongly doubt that holding 100 million ratings in memory at the same time is going to be the solution.

Comment: Ok Martijin!! I will work out myself!! But I am not even able to store the values in the list.. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Specifying what you want to do with those lists might also help answering the question.

Comment: Each list will hold movie id, customer id, rating of all users...After storing the values I'll use for the computation @user161151

Comment: What computation? Querying? Modifying?

Comment: Querying @user161151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomend going for SQLite database file instead. It's pretty easy to use and manage, and actually it is very efficient, in my opinion. If you put everything in memory at the same time, when the memory-based database grows you will end up in trouble.

Comment: Thanks Victor Domingos!! I'll try to do that!!

Comment: In case this is your first time using SQLite in Python, you may want to check these introductory tutorials: [SQLite Python Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm), [Introduction to SQLite in Python](http://pythoncentral.io/introduction-to-sqlite-in-python/), and [A thorough guide to SQLite database operations in Python](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_sqlite_in_python_tutorial.html). I hope it helps!